# Is there a way to specify inputs and outputs for structures?

Tags: factorio

If you look at the screenshot below, you can see one of my oil refineries.

I want to know if it is possible to switch which output say petroleum gas uses.  Currently it uses the top right of the refinery to exit.  I would rather is be on the left, as my chemical plant that uses the petroleum to make plastic is over that way.  I have to make a more complex configuration of my oil field because of the petroleum.

I also know that in the future, advanced oil processing makes it so that a refinery uses water and crude oil.  Is it possible to switch the inputs as well?

[image: Oil Refinery]

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in vanilla, afaik. You've got to work around the set inputs. Hopefully this changes at some point, but for now, there's nothing you can do besides modding the game.

And speaking of modding, I believe this mod will do what you want for inputs at least http://www.factoriomods.com/mods/gdiw-gha-darnitwater

Comment: factoriomods is the old and busted way.  New hotness: https://mods.factorio.com/mods/DaCyclops/GDIW.   Also, while/if you're modding: Flow Control.  For the "non-promiscuous" pipes alone.

Comment: Hey, bub, thanks for the link to https://mods.factorio.com/mods/DaCyclops/GDIW However, given that my answer is out of date, why not make your own answer and put me in my out of date place.     Also, does this new mod allow switching input/output positions?

Comment: You're not out of date, it's the same mod, it's just that the mod portal is now the official way to get mods.  And the in-game mod management is coming along nicely.

Comment: Using this mod (though was very helpful) unfortunately deactivated achievements.  The in game notifications would still pop saying the achievement unlocked, but Steam did not reflect them as being unlocked.  I'm hoping in the up coming 1.0 release they will implement a system to switch these in the vanilla game.