# Do mods make you ineligible for Steam achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, terraria

I've modded Terraria with TModLoader and Thorium.

I have achieved most of the Steam achievements already but am wondering if these (or any other) mods can prevent me from getting the remaining achievements.

Answer (score 3):

**Generally not**!

If the mods do not change content, mechanics or events which triggers the achievement, they are no problem.

Comment: I can speak to this. However, In [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/287520/is-there-a-way-to-specify-inputs-and-outputs-for-structures) someone provided a mod as a solution that worked great, except it deactivated Steam achievements.  Whats worse is the game said I unlocked achievements as I was playing, but they were still locked in Steam.  I didn't realize this was the case for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Steam doesn't disable achievements,developers can disable achievements if you install mods or something else in game. Some games check for mods like Skyrim SE and disable achievements until you disable or delete the mods. In many single player games, developers don't disable achievements because you don't get any advantage in game if you complete any achievements.